# iphone: deployment target

Tags: iphone, deployment, appstore-approval

How is this possible? I configured my iPhone app like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I pushed it into the App Store and now Apple says:

> You have indicated that your binary
>   requires iOS 4.3 or later. Apps that
>   require iOS 4.3 or later will not be
>   available to Verizon iPhone users.

Do I have to change the Base SDK to target iPhone 3.0 platform???
How can I do this?
Thx!

ANSWER:
If you leave the default 3.0 value the iOS Deployment Target is not shown/set which means the latest iOS will be selected? This is the xcode4 bug I beleave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XCode 4 it really easy to fix. Click on your project then go to the summary tab and you should see the Deployment Target drop down to select your target. This is a shortcut for the Build Setting.

I would like to add that I hope you have tested your application on previous versions of iOS before deploying your app. Currently your application will have weak references to the API and all new API calls will compile fine, but will crash when run on older devices if you do not use the proper runtime checks.

**Edit**
The image did not show up when I answered your question. Double check inside your build settings the deployment target is the same for Debug, Release and Distribution

Comment: as you can see I have 3.0 selected but apple ignored that!

Comment: The image did not show when I originally answered but inside of your build settings expand `iOS Deployment Target` and make sure all of your configurations are set to the same value.

Comment: aha... so if I leave the default 3.0 valu the iOS Deployment Target is not shown which means the latest OS? Is that it?

Comment: The search results do not seem to find all of the individual settings for each release type and they can be set independently.